# How to render a get petition at React.js component?

Tags: reactjs, get

im trying to render a `get` petition in a React.js component but I`m getting nothing. This is my components code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';

export default function ViewFolder(props){
    const params = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.tasks);
    const list = useSelector((state) => state.folders);
    const [folder, setFolder] = React.useState({});

    React.useEffect(async() => {
        if(!list || list.length == 0) return;

        setFolder(list.find((oneItem) => oneItem.id == params.id));

    }, [params, list]);

    React.useEffect(async() => {
        try{
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/to-do');

            dispatch({
                type: 'LIST_TASKS',
                list: res.data
            });
        }
        catch(e){
            swal("Oops!", e.message, "error");
        }
    }, []);

    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Folder: {folder.name}</h1>
            </div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                {tasks.find((oneItem) => oneItem.folder_id == folder.id) ? (
                                    <li>Tasks:
                                        <ul>
                                            {tasks.map((oneItem) =>
                                                oneItem.folder_id == folder.id ? (
                                                    <li>{oneItem.name}</li>
                                                ) : null
                                            )}
                                        </ul>
                                    </li> ) : <li> There are no tasks in this folder yet</li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <Link to='/task/add'>Add Task</Link>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Link to={'/folder/list'}>Back to folders list</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

If you need more code just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Check your browser developer tools for any errors and in network tab for any CORS error.  Did you try your API from Postman and are you getting response there? Or just paste your API URL in Chrome, are you getting anything?

Comment: Hi, i did check the api from Postman and it's fine but i can't render it at React. I think the problem here must be some error when trying to show the tasks inside its folders. Tasks has a foreign key "folder_id" that links it to the corresponding folder.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'folder_id')

it's pointing a mistake at: {tasks.find((oneItem) => oneItem.folder_id == folder.id) ? (

Comment: Check your tasks object some of the values are either null or doesn't contain a property `folder_id `

Comment: What's the response in the network tab in developer tool for the API call `http://localhost:3000/to-do`? What's the status code? Is it 200 and data empty?

Comment: Solved it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great !!!!.....